# WSO2 : IS and APIM integration

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have been trying to integrate the APIM and IS together for WSO2. I am currently using APIM as version 2.5.0 and IS as 5.6.0

I am referring this link for the complete setup
(https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0#)

Now, in the first step where it is asking to install the API keymanagement feature, I am getting below error

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - Api management Key Manager Feature 6.0.4 (org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymanager.feature.group 6.0.4) Software currently installed: OAuth Feature 6.0.14 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.feature.group 6.0.14) Only one of the following can be installed at once: Identity OAuth Server Feature 6.0.14 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.jar 6.0.14) Identity OAuth Server Feature 5.1.1 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.jar 5.1.1) Identity OAuth Server Feature 5.1.3 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.jar 5.1.3) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Api management Key Manager Feature 6.0.4 (org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymanager.feature.group 6.0.4) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.group [5.1.1,5.2.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: OAuth Feature 6.0.14 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.feature.group 6.0.14) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.group [6.0.14] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity OAuth Server Feature 5.1.1 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.group 5.1.1) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.jar [5.1.1] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity OAuth Server Feature 5.1.3 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.group 5.1.3) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.jar [5.1.3] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Identity OAuth Server Feature 6.0.14 (org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.group 6.0.14) To: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.server.feature.jar [6.0.14]

I skipped this steps and completed the other steps fully.

Now, I am able to open IS dashboard, APIM publisher and store properly but when I am trying to generate one token from Store dashboard to invoke any API, I am getting below error:

ERROR - AbstractKeyManager Can not create OAuth application  : DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://localhost:9445/services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:381)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:456)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:1126)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:693)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:125)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:140)
ERROR - APIUtil Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException(AbstractKeyManager.java:161)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:140)

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://localhost:9445/services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:381)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:456)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:1126)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:693)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:125)
        ... 81 more
[2019-02-15 11:46:59,877] ERROR - ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor Error occurred when updating the status of the Application creation process
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1416)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:165)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:3035)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:34)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:346)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c2._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:41)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c2.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_10(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:35)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException(AbstractKeyManager.java:161)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:140)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR) https://localhost:9445/services/APIKeyMgtSubscriberService
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:381)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:456)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:227)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:1126)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:693)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:125)
        ... 81 more
[2019-02-15 11:46:59,894] ERROR - APIConsumerImpl Could not execute Workflow
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.

Could not paste the complete other lines as the limit of chars got completed.
But these are the errors which I am getting in generating the Token for an application in store.

Can some one please cehck and let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing the keymanager features, can you download the pre-packed wso2 IS as keymanager pack from https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager#ConfiguringWSO2IdentityServerasaKeyManager-Step1-DownloadtheprepackagedWSO2ISastheKeyManager . This is a WSO2 IS pack with keymanager features installed.